# how do I backup apps stored on the phone?

Tags: itunes, backup

I've recently made iTune backups (not iCloud) of my iDevices and iTunes copied the apps to the local drive. I tried doing the same thing on my wife's iPhone but the apps arent' getting copied. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. But I'm only pressing backup on iTunes.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File -> Devices -> Transfer Purchases from "iPhone"`. If that doesn't do it, authorize first with `Store -> Authorize This Computer...` with the same Apple ID you used to purchase those apps, and then try again.

Comment: hello. I just tried your suggestion (using iOS9 and iTunes 12.3) on 2 MacBooks and it didn't work! :/